# Comma seperated value in select with order by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably a very common question but maybe with another twist.

I have two tables which I join and want to get comma seperated values of a particular column of second table

```
  select name,(Comma seperated scores) 'Scores' from Person Inner join Score 
  on Person.Id=Score.PersonId

  Example Output 

  name    Scores
  User1   zd,ad,cm
```

I have read that It can be done  by having another function, but probably that's not very performance oriented also I want the Scores strings to be ordered by in ascending order.  i.e   ad,cm,zd

Is there a way to do it by continuing to use only Inner Joins ?

Comment: What database engine?  mySQL (`group_Concat()`), SQL SERVER (`List_Agg()` if correction version or `for XML path`),  Oracle (`List_Agg()`, or `WM_CONCAT()`) depending on version?  Most support an order by within the aggregrate function.

Comment: The answer depends on the database you are using.  You can probably google:  "<your database name> group_concat()" for answers for your database.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight . . . This question is not about *storing* such values; it is about returning them.  And people being, well, human, sometimes like to see things in that format.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oops, you are absolutely right!

Comment: apologies, added ms-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT name
      ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + score 
         FROM Score AS s 
         WHERE s.PersonId=p.PersonId 
         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS CSV_Scores
FROM Person AS p;
```

The query will call the rows from table `Person` and then use `FOR XML PATH()` to get a comma separated string. `STUFF` is used to cut away the first comma.

### UPDATE: *stand-alone* example with `ORDER BY Score`:

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE(PersonID INT IDENTITY,Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Person VALUES('Jim'),('Jane');
DECLARE @Score TABLE(ScoreID INT IDENTITY, PersonID INT,Score VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Score VALUES(1,'ba'),(1,'db'),(1,'ac')
                        ,(2,'ba'),(2,'ab');  

SELECT name
      ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + score 
         FROM @Score AS s 
         WHERE s.PersonId=p.PersonId 
         ORDER BY s.Score
         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS CSV_Scores
FROM @Person AS p;
```

The result

```
name    CSV_Scores
Jim     ac,ba,db
Jane    ab,ba
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted.thnks